# Agrupar uma coluna por uma quantidade de dados específica

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Olá,
Estou tentando fazer uma consulta em um dataset do Airbnb no Python onde gostaria de agrupar por bairros e saber quais imoveis tem o shape(quantidade) maior que 30.

Eu fiz esse agrupamento abaixo de bairro pela média de preços porém tem alguns imóveis que tem um shape muito pequeno e gostaria de filtrar somente os que tem mais de 30.

Usei o código abaixo

```
df_clean.groupby(['neighbourhood']).price.mean().sort_values(ascending=False)[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtre o dataframe antes de agrupá-lo

```
df_clean[df_clean["shape"] > 30].groupby(['neighbourhood']).price.mean().sort_values(ascending=False)[:10]
```

Veja *Boolean Indexing* na [documentacao](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html?highlight=select#boolean-indexing)